# Andengine chopped number in Text

Tags: android, andengine

I use Text in Andengine and KozGoPr6N-Heavy. I use it in this way

```
Font font = FontFactory.createFromAsset(activity.getFontManager(), activity.getTextureManager(),256, 256, activity.getAssets(), "font/KozGoPr6N-Heavy.otf", 60, true, Color.WHITE);
font.load();
timerLabel = new Text(-90, 0, font, Integer.toString(0), 6, activity.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
```

But effect is not as I expect, it looks like chopped on left.

[image]

Any idea why?

Comment: check by increasing your texture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Show us how you use your FontREgion. You probably use TextureOptions.DEFAULT while TextureOptions.BILINEAR will be better choice.

This is how I create font, you should do similiar:

```
public void loadMenuFonts(){
FontFactory.setAssetBasePath("font/");
final ITexture mainFontTexture = new BitmapTextureAtlas(activity.getTextureManager(), 256, 256, TextureOptions.BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA);

mainFont = FontFactory.createStrokeFromAsset(activity.getFontManager(), mainFontTexture, activity.getAssets(), "mainFont.ttf", 30, true, Color.WHITE, 2, Color.rgb(22, 144, 189));

mainFont.load();
}
```

Notice that I use createStrokeFromAsset but you can simply use createFromAsset instead which is almost the same but the effect is font without stroke.